# Does dynamic memory allocation reduce performace?

Tags: c++, c

I went through the [video by Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo) where he explains why to avoid Linked Lists.

Basically, when memory is dynamically allocated using pointers, there are more number of cache misses which reduces the performance.

But, if the same thing is applied to Non-Linear Data Structures like trees and graphs, does the same thing hold true?

Because, in trees also we have two pointers for each node and again there will be random movements of the pointers leading to cache misses.

But, trees have been proved to perform better than linear data structures. Of course, trees can be implemented using arrays as well but again there is a huge consumption of memory.

My question is: **Is dynamic memory allocation good or not?**

Comment: "Is dynamic memory allocation good or not?".This isn't a good question. Dynamic memory allocation is sometimes _needed_. The question title is actually more interesting, though you should expect a good answer to contain at least once "it depends".

Comment: Your question is: **Is dynamic memory allocation good or not?** My answer is: **Yes.**

Comment: Yes, it can be relatively slow. That is why people use memory pools to eliminate lots of small allocations. Is dynamic memory allocation bad? LOL... it is for stuff you cannot do otherwise, so it is far from bad, in fact it is very very good since it enables you to do more stuff, naturally if you use it when you don't have to, it is bad, just like everything else.

Comment: "trees have been proved to perform better than linear data structure" - not necessarily. Iterating over an array will probably be faster than iterating over a tree (because of the cache locality you refer to); and a binary search will probably be faster in a sorted array, unless the tree is perfectly balanced.

Comment: Here is another [video from Herb Sutter](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661) that goes into some detail about this with very nice graphs, diagrams, explanations etc. from around the 23:30 mark and he picks up on some of Bjarne's material at around the 46:00 mark.

Comment: Dynamic allocation comes at a cost, yes. There's overhead on both the programmers' side and an impact on the execution time. So in an ideal world, we wouldn't ***have*** to use it. This being reality, things aren't ideal and sometimes (actually, rather often) we **NEED** dynamic memory allocation. The rule of thumb being: avoid when possible, but be realistic: you can't do much without it. PS: One of the reasons mentioned in the video is the overhead caused by indirection... if you want to know if indirection is bad: try writing a meaningful program without indirection

Comment: It is not dynamic allocation that is the problem here. It is how that dynamic allocation is organized and used. To that effect contiguous blocks have some clear advantages with current processor technology.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem but there are standard ways to implement them right? We need indirections for trees for example to  fetch the leaf nodes, I need to start from root always, right?

Comment: @xxx: Yes, and no... Whenever you pass an array to a function, you have indirection (it decays into a pointer), whenever you pass the memory address of a var to a function, you have indirection. Indirection isn't restricted to data structures. You can search a tree in a variety of ways, not always starting at the root (wiki tree traversal). It all depends on what you need, when and where you need it. You can also pass a pointer to a single leaf node around, it doesn't matter: indirection is the name of the game

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He was trying to make the point that a lot of indirection between small objects tends to decrease the cache efficiency of the code. You cannot fully avoid linked structures, but in some cases you can prefer a "flat" layout which fits into an entire cache line, for example.

Trees and linked-lists are both linked structures which rely on dynamic memory allocation, but lists are considered "bad" because they are `O(n)`, and almost every chase of the `next` pointer results in a cache miss. In general, `n` misses is a lot worse than `log(n)` misses.

For example, consider the following two structs:

```
struct point {
    int x, y;
};

struct rect {
    struct point origin;
    struct point size;
};
```

Even though `rect` contains two `point` structs, the entire `rect` struct is totally "flat" because the inner structs are contained, not referred to via pointers. This flatness is a nice thing because `rect` can now fit on a cache line, and accessing `origin.x`, for example, wouldn't incur a cache miss after the initial one for the struct itself.

Further, because the stack is typically "hot" in the cache, it would make sense to allocate the entire `rect` structure there, and not on the heap. It's not only the overhead of the dynamic allocation itself, it is also that the address returned by the allocator is likely not yet in the cache.

Answer (score 2):

Data structures are an abstract concept. They're not tied to the language, much less to the library that implements some of them (in this case `std`).

A tree is better at lookup than an array not because the memory is allocated statically or dynamically (which can be both for both data structures), but because of the algorithms used to search through it.

However, most often than not, an array will outperform a tree when it comes to traversing all nodes (both because of the easier algorithm **and** implementation details - faster caching due to linear allocation).

Better use a data structure that makes sense for the operations you plan to perform on it. You can always provide a custom allocator that handles the allocation. But, again, allocation is orthogonal. There's algorithm efficiency, and there's low-level efficiency. And there's a trade-off. If you decouple your design enough, you should be able to switch between data structures easily and do it if performance is impacted enough.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you want to allocate memory dynamically or on the stack depends entirely on your implementation. In general, you use the stack if the the variable or object only lives inside a function, and you use the heap if the variable or object has to live inside the entire program and be manipulated by multiple functions.

Comment: Global stack variables fall in to what category according to you?

Comment: Yes...should have thought more about that. They are indeed on the stack on a global level.